# Use string as Object method

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

Basically, I'm creating a small script that will update AD attributes (for a super user, not admin).

I've got a number of attributes, but I need a custom field so that the user can type in the AD attribute and then it will be searched by an LDAP query and displayed using objUser.

Here is the code:

```
Do While z = True
    attrchoice = InputBox("Please enter the custom attribute you wish to edit", "Custom Attribute")
    MsgBox "You have selected " & objUser.+attrchoice, vbOKOnly+vbInformation, objUser.displayName
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrlf & "Attribute cannot be found, please try again", vbOKOnly+vbExclamation, "Error"
    Else
        z = false
    End If
    On Error Goto 0

Loop
```

As you can see, I've tried doing the objUser. attribute part a few different ways - but I'm just not sure how to use a string that's input by the user.

In that custom field, the user could put "mail" and the code run would be objUser.mail - does that make sense?

If you need more information, please say.

Obviously, I've set my objects further up in the script and there are other parts to the script. All are working okay, for example:

```
telchoice = MsgBox("User's current telephone number is " & objUser.telephoneNumber & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
"Do you want to change the user's telephone number?", vbYesNo+vbQuestion, objUser.displayName)

If telchoice = 6 Then
    newtel = InputBox("Please enter the new telephone number", "Telephone Number", objUser.telephoneNumber)

    If Not adoRecord.EOF Then
        On Error Resume Next
        objUser.Put "telephoneNumber", newtel
        objUser.SetInfo
        On Error Goto 0
    End If
    MsgBox "User's new telephone number is now " & objUser.telephoneNumber, vbOKOnly+vbInformation, objUser.displayName
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [`Get()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
strValue = objUser.Get(attrchoice)
```

I see you're already using the `Put()` function later on to assign values to attributes. It's similar, but opposite.

Comment: That's the one Bond! Thanks a lot, all working now. Learnt about Get() today too. :)